# Using DocuSign API, how do I apply base64 encrypted string to template?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am able to create a composite envelope and generate an embedded sending URL. Envelope consists of a mix of templates and PDFs (base64 strings) that are dynamically generated via Microsoft Reporting Services. New requirement is to exclude some PDFs from external users.  I would like to apply these PDFs to templates, so that template builders can control visibility. This can be done manually by selecting PDF in sender view, selecting ellipsis then Apply Templates. Can this be done using DocuSign API, or is my only option to assign values to excludedDocuments at the signer level?

Comment: are you trying to apply a template to an envelope that was not created from that template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of what the DocuSign web tool does can be done via API calls. In some cases you'll need to use the v2.1 API (which is now available and recommended).

You can see what API calls the DocuSign web tool is using via [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging).

Note that the DocuSign web tool often builds up envelopes gradually. You don't have to do that in most cases.